# How to remove Ubuntu entries from UEFI

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, uefi, efi

I 've got an issue with my UEFI boot values.
In the past I installed Ubuntu 14.10 LTS as a dual-boot system.
It was working ok, until I decited to remove it.
I deleted the Ubuntu partitions and merged them with my Windows partition.
Everything is working fine, except when I check the Boot Menu inside the BIOS, there is still a value considering Ubuntu.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8Vd2.jpg

I followed this guide: https://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi but the value is still remaining there. Is there a way to completeley remove it without loosing the values that point to my Windwows system.

My Laptop is a Lenovo G50-70

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you try the native Windows commands listed at http://superuser.com/a/563908/420034

Comment: This is not a programming question, so off-topic here. Try [Superuser](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot a live Linux cd using legacy, have a USB stick with you.

1. Run lsblk to find out where your efi partition is

   ```
   $ lsblk
   ```
2. Mount that efi partition and your USB stick to 2 separate folders (replace sda1 with the path of your efi partition and sdb1 with the path of your USB.

   ```
   $ mkdir /mnt/usb
   $ mkdir /mnt/efi
   $ mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/efi
   $ mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/usb
   ```
3. Cd into the EFI folder of the efi partition

   ```
   $ cd /mnt/efi/EFI
   ```
4. Move the folder "ubuntu" into the USB so you can restore it if something goes wrong

   ```
   $ mv ubuntu /mnt/usb
   ```

Done!

Comment: Complete method (if to be done in Windows): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyOBF2ePvHY